# How can read config file in Net5?

Tags: vb.net, .net-5

I using Vb.net , FW: Net5

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectString" value="DB/Sample.db3" />
  </appSettings>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I install `"System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager"` from Nuget

I had try get config as:

```
Dim str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectString")
```

But it occur exception error:

```
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

How can read app.config in VB Net5?

Comment: Instead of using the `<appSettings>` element, I suggest that you use the Settings page of the project properties to add a setting of type `(Connection string)` if you can. It may depend on whether you have an appropriate provider installed. I'm not sure what would be required for a data source of that type as it's not one I've used myself. Assuming that you can do as suggested, you can then access the value using `My.Settings.ConnectString`, where the property name is whatever name you gave to the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using an app.config file in a .NET 5.0 app and I got the same exception. Unlike you, I looked a bit further and saw that it also said that it encountered an unknown section, i.e. system.diagnostics. I then commented out the `<system.diagnostics>` element in my config file and it worked as expected. I'm not sure what you would do if you actually needed to use that section but it doesn't look like you do so it shouldn't be a problem to comment it out or delete it.

Comment: Thanks, delete system.diagnostics , it is working.